# how can I create secure controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl

I'm new to rails. I want to create secure control.

here what I did :
I created a secure and change routes.rb as

```
scope :constraints => {:protocol => 'https'} do
  get "secure/index"
end
```

but, I.m having this error

> [2012-10-08 12:07:07] ERROR bad URI `\x12p\x00\x00H\x00��'.
>   [2012-10-08 12:07:07] ERROR bad URI`pqn���|�լ%[�y���\x00\x00H\x00��'.

when I request `https://localhost:3000/secure`

thanx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that you have a misunderstanding of secure http communication!

http and https are two different things. thats why they usually work on two different ports! http is 80 and https is usually 443.

https needs a signed certificate and which is usually handled by your webserver (apache, nginx etc). it's also possible to handle the https stuff within rails and there are some nice gems to handle configuring ssl-enforcement.

have a look at this post to get started: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

Comment: thanx for your response. I'm going to change the sever configuration to serve ssl

Comment: As @phoet said I misunderstand what I want. And found answer to my question form [Setup WEBrick to Serve SSL (HTTPS) as well as Non-SSL (HTTP) Traffic Side-by-Side](http://blog.readypulse.com/2012/01/19/setup-webrick-to-serve-ssl-https-as-well-as-non-ssl-http-traffic-side-by-side/) blog post.